# How to determine WCF message size at the encoder level

Tags: wcf, compression, gzip, message, encoder

I am building a custom encoder that compresses WCF responses.  It is based on the Gzip encoder in Microsoft's WCF samples and this blog post:

http://frenk.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/gzip-compression-wcfsilverlight/

I've got it all working, but now I would like to apply the compression only if the reply is beyond a certain size, but I am not sure how to retrieve the total size of the actual message from the encoder level.

I would need to get the message size at both the WriteMessage(...) method in the EncoderFactory, so I know whether to compress the message) and at the BeforeSendReply(...) method in the DispatchMessageInspector so that I can add the "gzip" ContentEncoding header to the response.  Requests are always small and not compressed, so I don't need to worry about that.

Any help appreciated.

Jon.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would do this in two stages. First, write a custom MessageEncoder that encodes the message to a `byte[]` just normal. Once you have the encoded byte-array (and this can be any message encoding format... Xml, Json, binary, whatever) you can examine the byte-array size and determine whether you want to create another compressed byte array.

Several resources you may find useful:

- [MSDN WCF Sample Code for a custom compression message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx)
- [Nicholas Allen's "Build a Custom Message Encoder" blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/05/09/592933.aspx). In this series He creates a "counting encoder" that basically wraps another encoder of any type and allows you to know what the encoded message size is (based on the `byte[]` size). You could probably adapt this and create a "ThresholdCompressionEncoder".

Answer (score 0):

You can try calculating it based on `reply.ToString.Length()` and `message.ToString.Length()`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but both the reply and the message are reference objects at that point (i'm using an custom inner encoder), so I can't get the length that way.  If I drill down into the object, I can get the actual content, which is still a reference object.  I'm not sure how to get a hold of the serialized raw data before it is sent.